# Kubernetes pods are communicating with other pods over load balancer instead of internally

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, kong-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster in AWS GovCloud. I have deployed the Kong Ingress Controller (private NLB) along with the kong-proxy service in namespace "kong". In namespace "A" I have deployed my applications along with an Ingress object resource. I have deployed Keycloak (authentication/authorization app), Statuses (custom Ruby on Rails app that returns the statuses of an operation - eg. 10%, 20%, 50%, 100% complete), and Operation A, a custom-built Java app that performs a calculation.

My flow:

Client --> Load Balancer DNS --> kong-proxy --> Ingress --> Keycloak service --> authenticate with Keycloak --> returns auth bearer **token** console output.

Client (me) passes **token** --> Load Balancer DNS --> kong-proxy --> Ingress --> Operation A service --> *authenticate and initialize Operation A*

Operation A service --> sends status update to Statuses service --> **connection refused error**

When troubleshooting the network flow, I see that Operation A is trying to connect to Statuses *via the load balancer's DNS name*:
Operation A service --> Load Balancer DNS --> kong-proxy --> Ingress --> Statuses service

But this is a very strange network flow. A pod shouldn't connect to another pod in the same cluster and namespace by going through a load balancer. It should just connect via the K8s internal DNS name: **name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port/path**

Is this an issue with the Kong ingress controller or should I be looking at my application config? Can any annotations or parameters be added to the ingress controller or ingress object manifests to correct this network pathing?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this? I am looking to implement something that requires recreating your issue intentionally (all traffic is passed externally rather than internally) so I would love to know the cause.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked through this issue. I would just make sure that your ingress rules are all correct. There is also more documentation on Nginx than on Kong, so I would swap for that if possible. Sorry I can't be of more help.